# Can't get a string that is already declared

Tags: java

I can't print a string that is already declared. Here's the code:

```
public class ignCalcu {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to CalcuLegends!");
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Before you use the Calcore, would you like to set an IGN first?");
            System.out.println("Yes or No?");
            String start = input.nextLine();
            if (start.equals("Yes") || start.equals("yes")){
                System.out.println("What is your favorite color?");
                String color = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("What word describes you the best?");
                String word = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Think of an animal other than dog or cat.");
                String animal = input.nextLine();
                input.close();
         
                String ign = (" "+color+"_"+word+"_"+animal);
                System.out.println("Your IGN is" + ign );
                break;
            }
            else if (start.equals("No") || start.equals("no")){
                break;
            }
            else;
            System.out.println("Invalid response. Please try again.");
        }
        System.out.println("hi "+ ign + "!");
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
source_file.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
         System.out.println("hi "+ ign + "!");
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable ign
  location: class ignCalcu
1 error
```

Comment: You need to read up on the scope of local variables.

Comment: It's not declared in the scope you want to use it in.

Comment: This line seems wrong: ` else;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outside of the scope. If you wan't to access ign outside of the loop, you need to declare it outside of the loop.

[Java Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_scope.asp)

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ign;

        System.out.println("Welcome to CalcuLegends!");
        
        while (true){
            ...

            ign = (" " + color + "_"  + word + "_" + animal);
        }
        
        System.out.println("hi "+ ign + "!");
}
```

Comment: But there are strings associated inside that string, and can only be inside the conditional scope

Comment: In your example, only ign is being used outside the loops scope. Once you set the value for ign, you no longer have any association with those other variables. Only the literal value of the string is stored in ign. but if you need to use color, word, and animal outside as well, then do the same. Declare the variables outside of the loop. You can update them inside of the loop.